# Magento Can we check which applied shopping cart rules in the order email template?

Tags: magento-1.9

I added a new rule and I need to change the shipping text in the order email depend on this rule So I need to check if it is applied.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the applied rule ids with :

```
$order->getAppliedRuleIds();
```